# Removing Reference Without Restarting Project

Tags: c#, excel, com, reference

I have two projects, one was a test, and the other is rather substantial. This is using C# WinForms on Visual Studio 2008.

On the Substantial project, I once had a reference to Office.Interop.Excel, and in doing so, it added a COM reference to Office14. This, however, caused it to not work on machines that did not contain that folder.

So, as a test, I downloaded a new third party DLL called EPPlus, where I made a quick and dirty one button program that does what the big one does but on a much smaller scale. Using the 3rd Party dll, I was able to get it working. It can read in an Excel file, write something to a specific cell, and then save it somewhere else.

However, when I then adopted that dll into my larger project, and did all I could to remove references to the COM Object Library, it still was looking for it on the other machines.

My question is, is there a way to sever this connection, or find a way to get rid of it for good without needing to remake my entire project?

Comment: You should be able to remove the reference and clean your project and build it, are you saying that is not happening?

Comment: When you get the exceptions, look at the stack trace to see what part of your code is trying to use the interop assemblies.

Comment: I did a clean and rebuild, and the error still occurred. I completely rebuilt my solution by wholesale copy/pasting all the code, and after a little tweaking (making sure the buttons worked), it worked just fine. I went back to the old one, did another clean and rebuild, and it crashed.